# Overflow css property is not supported in older version of IPhone(iphone 3G- iOS 4.2.1)

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, html-lists

While developing an iPhone application with phone-gap, it was a requirement to display a list of items.

I have used jquery mobile and created an unordered list

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="list1">
      <li> List item1</li>
      <li> List item2</li>
  </ul>
```

When scrolling down to a long list the page header is getting vanished, so tried fixing the header using "**data-postion**" attribute of jquery mobile. But due to poor performance I changed that to a scrollable list using **overflow** property(However the scrolling functionality was not too good). CSS was like this

```
#listWrapper{
        position:fixed; 
        overflow:auto;
        height:330px;
   }
```

It worked fine in IPhone 4s but not in lower version of IPhone. Is there is any alternative to overflow property? Or any other possible fixes for this?

Is there any way to display list of items (**with fixed height and scroll functionality**) in Phonegap(iOS) without moving the entire page content.

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the js-library: iScroll. It is really easy and works great.
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Just declare a wrapper div around your list.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ...
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then instance an "iScroll" with the id of your wrapper-div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
</script>
```

Comment: we have already tried this solution. However we found issue with Android ... Its working not well with Android.Also we need the same scrolling functionality with Table.. so that we used the overflow and we found that there is a delay in scrolling also its not working with android!!!

Comment: I am currently working on a webapp for iPhone and Android and I have the same issue with Android 2.3.5 and lower. However the performance for 4< is better than iPhone 4 and 3GS. 
I think the problem is the poor CSS rendering of the Android web browser. The scroll in JQM is using CSS-property 'transform3d', the same as iScroll. I don't think that there is a satisfactory solution other than making the app native through PhoneGap